# Counting the amount of N digit numbers made from K digits divisible by X.

Tags: number-theory

Look at the problem from this way:

N is a number, for example it's **4**.
K would be an array of digits, like: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
X is again, a number, let's say it's **11**.

How do I count the amount of numbers matching these circumstances?

How I am currently doing this is:

1. Create an array (I will call it `allnumbers`) of all numbers between the smallest possible number made with the specified digits from K (`== 1001`) AND the biggest possible number created using the highest digit from K, repeated as many times as the amount of N (`== 3333`) that are divisible by X.
2. Eliminate/remove all numbers from the `allnumbers` array that contain different digits from the ones specified under K
3. Return the length of `allnumbers` as the amount

I believe the final answer is `34`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. You can be more efficient by combining steps 1 and 2, only generating numbers that contain the proper digits.  You can use a set of nested loops, each running $|K|$ times.  If $K$ were $\{3,5\}$ you would generate $3333, 3335, 3353, \ldots 5555$ Depending on $X$, you can be more clever and not do step 3. If $X=2,$ only take even digits for the ones digit. In some cases you can prove that $\frac 1X$ of the $|K|^N$ numbers are divisible by $X$ and you don't have to generate the numbers at all. If $K$ were all digits, you would have $0000$ through $9999$ and we know that $\frac1{11}$ of these, $910$ of them are divisible by $11$ without checking each one.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more deeply? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @DJDavid98:  Did this help?  If you still have questions, it would help if they were more specific.

Comment: Close enough, thanks.